# How to replace a pattern partially?

Tags: vim, sed, vi

When I was using VIM, I got a simple question:

Replace the pattern `",\s\d\t))` with `",\s\d))`.

For example:

Change the following

```
...roid", 1 ));
...id", 0  ));
...lite", 1  ));
...
```

To

```
...roid", 1));
...id", 0));
...lite", 1));
...
```

I tried `%s/",\s\d\t/",\s\d))/gc`, but it changed them to `...roid",sd));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backreferences.

```
%s/",(\s\d)\t/",\1))/gc
```

Here, `(\s\d)` is a capture group. The `\1` refers to the capture group.

Comment: It works finally, after I changed it to `%s/",\(\s\d\)\t/",\1/gc`. Thanks!

Comment: I thought as much...though the expression did not seem to match the output in your question.